# What is the geometric interpretation of a unit circle having a line integral of zero along a curve?

Tags: integration

Let C be an arbitrary arc of the unit circle. Give a geometrical interpretation for ∫C∇f·dr= 0 where f(x,y)=x^2+y^2.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of the scalar field $f$ with respect to arc length on the curve is

$$ \int_C f(x,y)\; ds $$

This is never $0$ unless the curve reduces to a single point, because $x^2 + y^2 > 0$ except at the origin.

But I suspect that's not the integral you're thinking of.
Please clarify.

EDIT: OK, so now you want
$$ \int_C (\nabla f) \cdot dr$$
For any continuously differentiable function $f$, and any curve that starts at a point $a$ and ends at a point $b$, that is $f(b) - f(a)$.  So in this case all you need for that to be $0$ is that $f$ is the same at the starting and ending points of the curve, i.e. both are on the same circle centred at the origin.

Comment: This was not the integral I was talking about. I just edited the original post to clarify what I meant.